# VirtualBox: VBoxManage modifyhd hosting on mac os x resize not supported

Tags: macos, resize, virtualbox

I'm hosting a VM on OS X using VirtualBox.  I'm trying to resize the virtual hard drive by using the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd [file path]/ubuntu_vm-disk1.vmdk --resize 16000
```

And I get the following error:

```
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

here is my showhdinfo:

```
Accessible:           yes
Logical size:         15719 MBytes
Current size on disk: 6066 MBytes
Type:                 normal (base)
Storage format:       VMDK
Format variant:       dynamic default
```

what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATED**
I removed all snapshots and retried the command with "" around the path and now getting following error:

```
VBoxManage: error: Failed to lock media when compacting '/Users/dwstein_old/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu_120723/ubuntu_vm-disk1.vmdk'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component Medium, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
Context: "Resize(cbResize, progress.asOutParam())" at line 522 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80BB0007) - Current object state prohibits operation (extended info not available)
```

Comment: This question has already been asked on serverfault and then migrated to superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/477022/virtualbox-vboxmanage-modifyhd-hosting-on-mac-os-x-resize-not-supported

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with 3 steps :

- cloning your VMDK to VDI format using VBoxManage
- resize the disk to create free space using VBoxManage
- modify the filesystem to allocate free space to your drive, using GParted

I wrote a tutorial here to [resize your VM Disk](http://www.ifusio.com/blog/resize-your-sda1-disk-of-your-vagrant-virtualbox-vm)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a permission issue. Just try the same command with an Administrator command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you need to convert it, then clone it, before trying to resize it. You have an extra first step to convert it. vmdk -> vdi

## 1. As tvial said, convert your vdmk file to vdi following step 1 in that [tutorial](https://tvi.al/tag/vm/)

Here it says use the `clonehd` command. So in your case it'll be exactly like:
`VBoxManage clonehd <ubuntu_vm-disk1.vmdk> <output-name-here-step1.vdi> --format vdi`

The actual steps from his tutorial are this:

```
# Go to the VM folder on your Host computer.
cd ~/VirtualBox VMs/VM-NAME  
# Since resize can't be applied to .vmdk, we'll convert the disk to .vdi format
VBoxManage clonehd box-disk1.vmdk box-disk1.vdi --format vdi  
# Output example : 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100% # Clone hard disk created in format 'vdi'. UUID: 49474a0a-c48c-4b15-8df0-0b9687b4bbaf
```

## 2. Clone steps

2a. Inside VirtualBox, create a new vm, with more allocated space.

2b.  (possibly skip this step) Run command `clonemedium` with the same output file name as in step 1 as the first parameter, and the vdi you just created  in step 2a as second parameter, in your case:
`VBoxManage clonemedium <output-name-here-step1.vdi> <name-of-vdi-step2a.vdi> --existing`

Don't forget the `--existing` at the end!

## 3. Follow rest of the steps here [great tutorial for OS X](https://medium.com/@akshay.g174_68301/increasing-virtualbox-vdi-capacity-on-mac-os-x-ac4d52b63f0c)

Finish the tutorial, resize the file. If running a VirtualBox 5.1.2 or newer, Use `modifymedium` instead of modifyhd. I used modifyhd but other resources say its deprecated in favor of modifymedium.

```
VBoxManage modifymedium --resize 1600 <name-of-vdi-step2a>.vdi
```

## 4. It should also be noted that Ubuntu (a VM of it) may *not* recognize the larger space allocated. You have to start the Ubuntu VM, then repartition it. Steps for that can be found [here](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/):

Answer (score 0):

My situation - Virtual box 6.0 with snapshots and dynamically allocated memory.

Backup your virtual machine and shut it down.

Step 1. - Delete the snapshots.

Step 2. - Using the command given below increase the virtual size.

```
VBoxManage modifymedium disk "\Path\To\Vdi\xyz.vdi" --resize XXXXX
```

(new size in MB)

Step 3. - Startup the virtual machine and open terminal.

Step 4. - This step will provide you with the list of all the drive partitions. in my case it was /dev/disk1's disk1s2 which was supposed to increase in size.

```
diskutil list
```

Step 5. -

```
diskutil repairdisk disk1
```

Step 6. -

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 124g
```

(here 124g is the size that i actually wanted it to be.)